# how to load all the file in a variable

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract substrings from a file which contains strings.
The file is like:

```
    >scaffold30     24194
    CTTAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGTGACTGAAGGAACTGAGAAAAAGAGCGAGCTGAAAGGAAGCATAGCCATTTGGGAGTGCCAGAGAGTTGGGAGG GAGGGAGGGCAGAGATGGAAGAAGAAAGGCAGAAATACAGGGAGATTGAGGATCACCAGGGAG.........
    .................
```

For the extraction of the substrings I am using a file with the coordinates of the start and end of the substrings.
The script that I wrote is:

```
open my $coords_info, $coords_file or die "Could not open $coords_file: $!";
open my $chr_info, $chrom or die "Could not open $chrom: $!";
my $count = 0;


while(my $sline = <$chr_info>) {
    if ($sline!~ m/^>/) {
            chomp $sline;
            print $sline;
    foreach(my $cline = <$coords_info>) {
            my@data = split('\t', $cline);
            my $start = $data[0];
            my $end = $data[1];
            my $offset = $end - $start;
           $count++;
           my $sub = substr($sline, $start+1, $offset);
           print ">conserved $count\n";
           print $sub;
            }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to load all the string of the file to the sline variable (and not line by line on each iteration, and after that, the foreach to extract the substring.
I know that it sounds a trivial problem, but could you help me please??
Thank you...

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: it gives me "Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC" I tryed

Comment: @Vasilis: File::Slurp isn't a standard Perl module.  You have to install it on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

read all file in one string variable:

```
{
   local $/ = undef;
   $variable = <$my_fh>;
}
```

read all file to array:

```
my @array = <$my_fh>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to slurp.

A [*Perl Maven* post](http://perlmaven.com/slurp) has been dedicated to Slurp principle. It explains how to implement it from scratch or using the [File::Slurp module from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Slurp) module.

Another approach is to use this one-liner [explained by Chromatic](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/a-one-line-slurp-in-perl-5.html):

```
my $contents = do { local $/ = <$fh> };
```

The [Perl6::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6::Slurp) module is also a convenient way to implement the Perl 6 *slurp* built-in function.